# How can I have both commas and brackets while printing a list? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, probability, binomial-theorem

I have to program a way to calculate binomial distribution in Python for pi as 0.1, 0.5 and 0.9. The desired input and output are as follows:

input: 3

output:

[0.729, 0.243, 0.027, 0.001]

[0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125]

[0.001, 0.027, 0.243, 0.729]

---

I have written the code but I can't seem to figure out how to have both brackets and commas in my output. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
n = int(input())
pi = [0.1, 0.5, 0.9]
dist = []
result = []

for i in pi:
    for j in range(0, n+1):
        dist.append(math.comb(n, j) * (i**j) * ((1-i)**(n-j)))

for i in dist:
    result.append(round(i, 3))

result = np.array(result)

print(result[:n+1])
print(result[n+1: 2*n+2])
print(result[2*n+2:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.join()` to do this sort of thing.

```
def print_pretty(result):
    print("[" + ", ".join(str(value) for value in result) + "]")
    
print_pretty(result[:n+1])
print_pretty(result[n+1: 2*n+2])
print_pretty(result[2*n+2:])
```

Result:

```
[0.729, 0.243, 0.027, 0.001]
[0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125]
[0.001, 0.027, 0.243, 0.729]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I really appreciate your help! Is there another way to do this without introducing a function?

Comment: You could use the statement outside the function. That is, `print("[" + ", ".join(str(value) for value in result[:n+1]) + "]")` would be the first print statement, and so on.